# How to get selected row data of kendo detail grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am able to get the selected row in kendo grid ( master grid), But I am unable to get the selected row data in detail grid. Please provide me a code sample.
Thanks,
abhi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is like for the main grid. Being `childgrid` the grid corresponding to details, do:

```
var row = childgrid.select();
var data = childgrid.dataItem(row);
console.log("row", row);
console.log("data", data);
```

Where I defined `master` grid as:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    detailInit: detailInit,
    ...
});
```

And details grid is created using the following function when a row in master grid is expanded:

```
function detailInit(e) {
    childgrid = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
        },
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: false,
        selectable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns:
                [
                    { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                    { field: "ShipCountry", title: "Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                    { field: "ShipAddress", title: "Ship Address" },
                    { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "200px" }
                ]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
}
```

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2M86L/ (When you click on `Show` button, its displays in the console of your browser the selected row and its data).

Comment: Thanks OnaBai , I am now able to do it , I was not getting the grid instance. It was my mistake.

Comment: I'm trying to select multiple rows from one grid & assing those rows to another grid. How can I do that? Please Help.

Comment: @Jain, you should not ask questions as comments since this will prevent others from finding the solution to an already asked question. Try posting a new question and I will be glad to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I did open a new question, but to be honest I was trying to get your attention! You helped me before & I know how good you are in kendo ui. Anyway I solved the problem.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved and no problem about using comments it just a question of helping others.

Comment: I was asking for this in some other place, Now I got it, thanks OnaBai.

Answer (score 0):

Here a somewhat simpler example on how to get to the data of the clicked row: http://jsfiddle.net/Corne/AQqMH/5/

This is the code where the magic happens:

```
change: function (arg) {            
    var selectedData = this.dataItem(this.select());

    // selectedData now points to the selected dataSource item!

    alert("Clicked id: " + selectedData.id);
}
```